# Looker node SDK custom config reader

Tags: javascript, node.js, sdk, looker

I am using looker SDK in node JS
The following solution is not working for me in node js.
I get this solution from https://github.com/looker-open-source/sdk-examples/blob/master/typescript/customConfigReader.ts

```
const { LookerNodeSDK, NodeSettings } = require("@looker/sdk-node");

/**
 * @class customConfigReader
 *
 * A custom configuration reader that overrides the readConfig() method
 * in NodeSettings to allow fetching client_id and client_secret
 * from anywhere.
 */
class customConfigReader extends NodeSettings {
  constructor(settings) {
    super(settings);
  }
  /**
   * @returns an IApiSection object containing client_id and client_secret
   */
  readConfig() {
    return {
      client_id: "clientId",
      client_secret: "clientSecret",
    };
  }
}

(async () => {
  const sdk = LookerNodeSDK.init31(
    new customConfigReader({
      base_url: "https://<your-looker-server>:19999",
    })
  );

  const me = await sdk.ok(
    sdk.me(
      "id, first_name, last_name, display_name, email, personal_space_id, home_space_id, group_ids, role_ids"
    )
  );
  console.log({ me });
})();
```

I have tried the Above solution in node JS and that not working.

```
class customConfigReader extends NodeSettings {
  constructor(settings,clientId,clientSecret) {
    super(settings);
    this.clientId=clientId;
    this.clientSecret=clientSecret;
  }
  /**
   * @returns an IApiSection object containing client_id and client_secret
   */
  readConfig() {
    return {
      client_id: this.clientId,
      client_secret: this.clientSecret,
    };
  }
}

 const sdk = LookerNodeSDK.init31(
      new customConfigReader({
        base_url: baseUrl,
      },clientId,clientSecret)
    );
  
    const response = await sdk.ok(
      sdk.me(
        "id, first_name, last_name, display_name, email, personal_space_id, home_space_id, group_ids, role_ids"
      )
    );
    console.log(response);
```

getting error

Error: TS-SDK configuration error:
Missing required configuration values like base_url

```
at new ApiSettings (C:\Users\DELL\Documents\GitHub\hawkeye-api\node_modules\@looker\sdk-rtl\lib\apiSettings.js:60:13)
at new NodeSettings (C:\Users\DELL\Documents\GitHub\hawkeye-api\node_modules\@looker\sdk-node\lib\nodeSettings.js:80:5)
at new customConfigReader (C:\Users\DELL\Documents\GitHub\hawkeye-api\services\looker.services.js:18:5)
at Object.authenticateLookerUser (C:\Users\DELL\Documents\GitHub\hawkeye-api\services\looker.services.js:65:7)
at C:\Users\DELL\Documents\GitHub\hawkeye-api\controllers\looker.controller.js:15:41
at C:\Users\DELL\Documents\GitHub\hawkeye-api\utils\catchAsync.js:2:19
at C:\Users\DELL\Documents\GitHub\hawkeye-api\controllers\looker.controller.js:7:5
at C:\Users\DELL\Documents\GitHub\hawkeye-api\utils\catchAsync.js:2:19
at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Users\DELL\Documents\GitHub\hawkeye-api\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
```